# How do I do bi-monthly subscriptions in Authorize.Net?

Tags: authorize.net

In the [API reference](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing-create-a-subscription), interval, length and unit are parameters, with the unit being either days or months. Is there a way to specify bi-monthly payments falling on the same date (say the 1st and 10th of each month) or do I have to set up two subscriptions (one for the 1st of each month and one for the 10th of each month)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose to use the ARB API, you would need to set up two different subscriptions as Authnet does not have a "day of month" option for subscriptions.

If you use the CIM API and manage the subscription yourself you would have more flexibility and could charge your users whenever you wanted to but you would be responsible for triggering every payment.